# SharePoint 2013 default favicon

Tags: sharepoint, favicon

I want to change the default favicon on my SharePoint site. I didn't want to change the masterpage, so I just replaced the favicon.ico file with the one I created (.ico) here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES. It still shows the default favicon even after I did iisreset. I would appreciate any suggestions / help. Thank you!

Comment: Try emptying the browser cache as well.

Comment: That didn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by uploading the generated favicon to [site]/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx and then changing the following line in the master page: < SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="[site]/SiteAssets/[your_favicon_name].ico" />.

Answer (score 0):

Changing favico must be done by

- Change the icon, as you suggested, in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES`
- Empty any browser cache
- Empty the IIS Temporary Cache if you have compression enabled `C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\`

  - (full path is `C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\SharePoint Central Administration v4\$^_gzip_C^\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WEB SERVER EXTENSIONS\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES`)
- Stop IIS and emtpy the temporary internet files, Start IIS

Run in PowerShell to delete Temporary ASP.NET Files

```
net stop w3svc
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*" -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*" -Force -Recurse
net start w3svc
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did all 3 steps, but it still displays the default favicon.

Comment: @user2916802 Updated with extra step

Comment: Solved it by uploading a favicon to the site assets and changing the url in the masterpage to that location. Anyways, thank you for your help!